# Visual Basic for Excel, cannot seem to find the best term to fix 'refresh' bug

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix this bug in Visual Basic. I've placed arrows where the problem is indicated with the debugger. I would really appreciate any help at all. Thank you!

```
Sub RefreshProfiles(Optional bck = "True")
    'Set warning messages
    LoadingProfiles = True
    Range("AA1").Formula = Range("AA1").Formula
    Range("AA2").Formula = Range("AA2").Formula
    Range("N9").Formula = Range("N9").Formula
    
    'Refresh Data
    With Sheets("Instructor Profile")
    Run
       'Reformat appearance
        .Rows("1:1").EntireRow.RowHeight = 150
        .Columns("A:AD").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    Sheets("Att-Pal Expiry").Range("A1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=bck
    Sheets("F&W").Range("A1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=bck
    
    Sheets("Updates").Range("A1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    
    'Recalculate warning messages
    LoadingProfiles = False
    Range("AA1").Formula = Range("AA1").Formula
    Range("AA2").Formula = Range("AA2").Formula
    Range("N9").Formula = Range("N9").Formula
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error and what is the error message?

Comment: Right now it's this line```` Sheets("Att-Pal Expiry").Range("A1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=bck````

When I mouse over it says 'True = True' but when I change the language I get 'Compile error, Expected: Expression.

Comment: My guess is `Optional bck As Boolean = True`. Also what's the random `Run` doing?

Comment: The 'run' part used to be called 'wun' so I assume my problem was that spelling error and I dont think anything is even supposed to be there.